# Problem on saving attribute. "The value of Admin must be unique."

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, migration, magento2.3.2

Currently, I'm migrating a website from Magento 1 to Magento 2. 
I've used the data migration tool and moved my data to Magento 2.

When I try to update a custom attribute called '`color_sw_selection`', an error occurs like this "**The value of Admin must be unique.**"

Even if I select the "**Unique Value**" property as "**No**".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

I'm using Magento 2.3.2

[image: Color attribute]

[image: Unique property]

[image: Error]

Comment: check for duplicates in Attribute option values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento 2 can not allow you to add duplicate Values of Your Attribute.**

The Unique value option is to control the attribute to be shared / not across other products.

[image]

Check the attributes listed in the error are not repeated in your attribute value.

**How to simulate this error:**

From default static content Attribute Activity has values for admin like Hike, outdoor values

[image]

Adding new values for admin (redundant values) Hike, outdoor

[image]

> Magento2 throws the below error

[image]

Comment: I got it. But I can save the same property on Magento 1. Did Magento change the way it works on Magento 2?

Comment: Unique option defines the value will be unique among all the other values of that attribute and not hat you can add duplicate values to your attribute.. here is a guide to that from docs https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html#advanced-attribute-properties

Comment: Thanks, your answer was clear. I wonder if Magento 1 was acting differently.